# Git workflow standard to handle multiple projects in development branch

Tags: git, workflow

So, this is the current problem in our organization. We have a small team that is working in multiple projects simultaneously.

We have a simple workflow, we have a dev and master branch, where dev is what is currently in QA and master is what is currently in production (or ready to production). However, this brings problems when we have, say, 3 featuresin QA and only one of those is ready to go to production, while the others are not.

This will make us cherry pick all the commits from that one feature to master, which is prone to error if the project spans many weeks of development. We could only send a feature to dev when it had been fully tested in QA, but sometimes we have the need of having multiple features in QA at the same time.

Is there a standard git workflow that is better suited to handle these situations? I read a solution on this blog that suggests creating dev branches for each project, but that would not solve our situation of having to have multiple projects in QA at the same time:

https://blog.logrocket.com/the-git-workflow-you-need-how-to-deal-with-multiple-teams-in-a-single-repository-faf5bb17a6e4

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATED* - The question was changed to indicate the problem is with the status of multiple features, rather than multiple projects as originally stated.  Original answer is preserved below.

---

There are many competing workflows that work for different teams/projects.  One fairly popular workflow is gitflow; it's probably better suited to larger projects, as it can seem like overkill for small/simple projects, but then again there is decent tool support for it.

In gitflow, `master` is "what has been released" and `develop` is 'what could potentially be released right now, if we were to do a release right now' - so you would not merge a feature to `develop` until it had passed QA testing.

This does raise questions about how to perform the best possible testing.  Obviously you'd need to test the `develop` version after features are merged in / before releasing, and it is possible that those tests would fail and you'd have to either hold the release for a bugfix, or roll one or more features back.  The goal would be to minimize how often that happens.

With a good infrastructure you could potentially deploy a given feature branch to the QA environment when you're ready to test that feature.  To get the best possible test, you could either merge develop into the feature before the test (possibly then undoing the merge afterward) or rebase the feature to `develop` before the test (if you don't mind feature branches being rewritten routinely).  So then if "everything releasable plus this one additional feature" passes testing, the one additional feature becomes "something releasable' and you can merge it to `develop`.

In practice, most projects I've seen compromise in some way, relying on the assumption that features won't interfere with one another (which is, of course, unduly optimistic, but still might work out most of the time).

---

The standard in git is to put each project in its own repository (the recent - and imo misguided - trend of 'monorepos' notwithstanding).  The situation you describe is a perfectly good example of why.

This is not to say that you *couldn't* devise some branching strategy that gets the same effect out of one repo - but what you'll likely have if you do, is separate 'logical repos' each comprising its own distinct set of branches, within "one repo".

Comment: Sorry, only now I noticed that I wrongly described "features" as projects. I meant 3 different features in QA instead of 3 different projects. Already corrected the initial post.